# how do I compare 2 json files and fetch the difference of only 2 key/value pairs and print them using python

Tags: python, json, jsonparser

I have 2 similar json files like below with the same keys. I need to find the difference of only one key in both the files (id_number) and store the name if there is a difference. Is there any way to do that?

```
[
 {
   "id_number": "SA4784",
   "name": "Mark",
   "birthdate": None
 },
 {
   "id_number": "V410Z8",
   "name": "Vincent",
   "birthdate": "15/02/1989"
 },
 {
   "id_number": "CZ1094",
   "name": "Paul",
   "birthdate": "27/09/1994"
 }
]
```

Comment: set(x.keys()) ^ set(y.keys()) something like that it will eliminate you the different key

Comment: The code you have written depicts a list of jsons/dictionaries. Can you explain a little more clearly what you want? Show 2 inputs and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the two files into dicts, step through them with a loop and on each iteration compare the id_number of each. If they're different, output the name field.

Answer (score 0):

> set(x.keys()) ^ set(y.keys())

something like that it will eliminate you the different key

Comment: It's not that simple. The operator suggested is for a bitwise binary XOR which won't help with JSON data.